# How to show that matrix $A,B$ are not similar?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A, B$ be $4\times 4$ square matrix given by,

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}0 &0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\\end{bmatrix}, B=\begin{bmatrix}0 &0&1&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0\\\end{bmatrix}$$

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{Property}& A & B\\\hline
 \text{Determinant}& 0& 0\\ \hline
 \text{Trace}& 0 &0 \\ \hline
 \text{Rank}& 2 & 2\\ \hline
\text{Char. Polynomial}& x^4 &x^4\\ \hline 
\end{array}

**I want to show that $A$ and $B$ are not similar.** All the problems I encountered so far were usually solved by showing that one of these above mentioned properties does not match.

How to approach this?

Comment: Jordan canonical form.

Comment: Compute and compare $A^2$ and $B^2$.

Comment: **Hint:** If $A = PBP^{-1}$, then $A^2 = PB^2 P^{-1}$.

Comment: @User8128 Thanks. So if $A$ is similar to $B$ then $A^n$ is similar to $B^n$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right! In this case, it should suffice just to look at $n=2$, but the property does hold in general (even for negative $n$ if $A$ and $B$ are invertible).

Comment: @User8128 In fact, you don’t want to go any farther than $n=2$ here since $A^n=B^n=0$ for $n\gt2$.

Answer (score 1):

According to the comments,  $A^2,B^2$ are not similar because

$\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\not= 0$.Yet, even if the previous product had been zero, $A,B$ would not have been similar. More generally

let $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&M\\0&0\end{pmatrix},B=\begin{pmatrix}0&U\\0&V\end{pmatrix}$ where each block has dimension $n\times n$, $M$ is invertible and $V\not=0$. Then $A,B$ are not similar (even if $V^2=0,UV=0$).

Proof. We show that if $Z=\begin{pmatrix}P&Q\\R&S\end{pmatrix}$ and $AZ=ZB$, then $\det(Z)=0$.

We obtain $MR=0$ and then $R=0$;

$SV=0$, then $\det(S)=0$;

$\det(Z)=\det(P)\det(S)=0$.  $\square$